# how to select an object from a list of objects by its attribute in python

Tags: python, oop

Apologies if this question has already been asked but I do not think I know the correct terminology to search for an appropriate solution through google.

I would like to select an object from a list of objects by the value of it's attribute, for example:

```
class Example():
    def __init__(self):
        self.pList = []
    def addPerson(self,name,number):
        self.pList.append(Person(self,name,number))

class Person():
    def __init__(self,name,number):
        self.nom = name
        self.num = number


a = Example()
a.addPerson('dave',123)
a.addPerson('mike',345)

a.pList #.... somehow select dave by giving the value 123
```

in my case the number will always be unique

Thanks for the help

Comment: in `self.pList.append(Person(self,name,number))`, `self` must not be one of the arguments. it is in the definition of `Person.__init__()` alright, but there it represents the newly created `Person` instance. you don't see it in `a = Example()`, either.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

One option is to use the `next()` built-in:

```
dave = next(person for person in a.pList if person.num == 123)
```

This will throw `StopIteration` if nothing is found. You can use the two-argument form of `next()` to provide a default value for that case:

```
dave = next(
    (person for person in a.pList if person.num == 123),
    None,
)
```

A slightly more verbose alternative is a for loop:

```
for person in a.pList:
    if person.num == 123:
        break
else:
    print "Not found."
    person = None
dave = person
```

Comment: I had not looked into next loops yet and it fixed my problem, cheers!

Comment: This is great, but how do we deal with stopIteration if it is empty?

Comment: @Jordan You can either catch the exception, or use the second code snippet in this answer.

Answer (score 6):

If those nom's are unique keys, and all you are ever going to do is access your persons using this unique key you should indeed rather use a dictionary.

However if you want to add more attributes over time and if you like to be able to retrieve one or more person by any of those attributes, you might want to go with a more complex solution:

```
class Example():
    def __init__(self):
        self.__pList = []
    def addPerson(self,name,number):
        self.__pList.append(Person(name,number))
    def findPerson(self, **kwargs):
        return next(self.__iterPerson(**kwargs))
    def allPersons(self, **kwargs):
        return list(self.__iterPerson(**kwargs))
    def __iterPerson(self, **kwargs):
        return (person for person in self.__pList if person.match(**kwargs))

class Person():
    def __init__(self,name,number):
        self.nom = name
        self.num = number
    def __repr__(self):
        return "Person('%s', %d)" % (self.nom, self.num) 
    def match(self, **kwargs):
        return all(getattr(self, key) == val for (key, val) in kwargs.items())
```

So let's assume we got one Mike and two Dave's

```
a = Example()
a.addPerson('dave',123)
a.addPerson('mike',345)
a.addPerson('dave',678)
```

Now you can find persons by number:

```
>>> a.findPerson(num=345)
Person('mike', 345)
```

Or by name:

```
>>> a.allPersons(nom='dave')
[Person('dave', 123), Person('dave', 678)]
```

Or both:

```
>>> a.findPerson(nom='dave', num=123)
Person('dave', 123)
```

Answer (score 3):

The terminology you need is 'map' or 'dictionnary' : this will lead you to [the right page in the python doc](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries).

Extremely basic example:

```
>>> a = {123:'dave', 345:'mike'}
>>> a[123]
'dave'
```

Comment: Thanks, the code I gave was an oversimplification, the Person class contained 7 attributes. I am pretty sure that is beyond the purpose of dictionaries, not sure about maps though

Answer (score 0):

The missing underscore makes `plist` a public property. I don't think that's what you want, since it does not encapsulate the functionality and you could call `a.plist.append` instead of `a.addPerson`.

```
class Example():
   ...
   def filter(self, criteria):
       for p in self.plist:
           if criteria(p):
               yield p

   def getByNum(self, num):
        return self.filter(lambda p: p.num == num)

dave = next(a.getByNum(123))
```

If the numbers are unique, you may also consider using a dictionary that maps from number to name or person instead of a list. But that's up to your implementation.