# Result of database query won't load into flask template

Tags: python, database, postgresql, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I changed the way I'm querying the database and although the result loads fine I cant get the information to show up in the template.

I tried rewriting the code in a simpler way to try and catch errors but found nothing. I am not sure what else to do.

```
from flask import render_template
from app import app, db


@app.route("/page")
def page():
    '''
    this is the old way that is useable in the template
    result = Test.query.filter_by(id=12))
    '''


    # test variables
    d = 65465
    s = 'rebrb'


    result = db.engine.execute('SELECT * FROM test WHERE id IN (183, 184, 180, 181, 182, 185, 95, 179)')
    # new way works here but not in the template
    print(result)
    for row in result:
        print(row.content)
    return render_template('page.html', s=s, d=d, result=result, title='Video')





'''
The d and s load but the for loop doesn't do anything 
'''
{{ d }}
{{ s }}
    {% for row in result %}
        {{ row }}
        {{ d }}
    {% endfor %}
```

The d and s variables show up but nothing past the for loop works.

**edit 1:** I made some progress by converting the result to a list before sending it to the template, but I feel like I shouldn't have to do that and I'm still looking for a better option.

**edit 2:** I found out I can also do the query this way.

```
result = Test.query.filter(Test.id.in_(183, 184, 180, 181, 182, 185, 95, 179))
```

Which works better but I need the result to be in the same order as the list

Comment: have you tried `{{ row.content }}` rather than just `{{ row }}` in the template?  Its been a while since I used raw SQL - I prefer SQLAlchemy and thats what I use now so I can't recall what kind of data structure the SQL query returns - but given you can print **row.content** in python, you should be able to get **row.content** out in the template... 'should' being the operative word...

Comment: @Steve I found out after a while that you can use sqlalcemy to do the same query and it works now.

Comment: @Steve Actually I found another problem, I need the row ids in the result to be in the same order as they are in the list. Do you know how to do that with sqlalchemy?

Comment: If you use Flask-SQLAlchemy you can use order_by method to sort results by specific column. result = Test.query.filter(Test.id.in_(95, 179, 180, 181, 182, 183, 184, 185)).order_by(Test.id).all()

Comment: I needed the results to show up in this order: (183, 184, 180, 181, 182, 185, 95, 179), I found out how here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29326297/sqlalchemy-filter-by-field-in-list-but-keep-original-order/45870732#45870732

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query I was trying to change to can be accomplished by using

```
result = Test.query.filter(Test.id.in_(95, 179, 180, 181, 182, 183, 184, 185))
```

without any extra problems.